# How to check Post request of this format using Postman

Tags: json, django, postman

I am checking [json](/questions/tagged/json) object post request using [postman](/questions/tagged/postman).The data is in format

```
 {
        "user": {
            "first_name": "Satyam",
            "last_name": "Gondhale",
            "username": "satyam@gmail.com",
            "email": "satyam@gmail.com",
            "groups": [],
            "is_active": true
        },
        "phone": "9028571487",
        "address": "Pune"
    }
```

Every time I am sending request I am getting error in postman is

```
 {
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

How to send this fields as a Post request using Postman to Django server

Comment: Use `body>raw` in POST

Comment: Maybe you should show some code? What's validating this?

Comment: Can you post an image of what this looks like in Postman please? Is that the response? What was the status code? Maybe include details about the Django server - The more details the better, it will help get an answer quicker.

Comment: I am getting Error code 400 Bad Request

Comment: you have a comma at the end of your data that shouldn't be there, unless this isn't all the data.

Comment: I have updated the request code for which I am checking the Post request using postman

Comment: Update the question with an image of Postman and your Django code - without that you're just asking people to basically guess an answer.

Comment: You haven't actually updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Start Postman
Click on **New**.
Select **New Request**

Change the Method from **Get** to **Post**

Set the URL you are using in the rightside of the field **POST**.

Then navigate to the Tab **Body** and paste your Code:

```
{
        "user": {
            "first_name": "Satyam",
            "last_name": "Gondhale",
            "username": "satyam@gmail.com",
            "email": "satyam@gmail.com",
            "groups": [],
            "is_active": true
        },
        "phone": "9028571487",
        "address": "Pune"
    }
```

See picture for example:

[image]

I think you also need to add a **Header**.

Navigate to the tab **Headers**
in the field **Key** add `Content-type`
in the field **Value** add `application/json`

[image]

Click then on **Send**.

then you should get a **response.**
Voilaa!

Regards

Xsi

Comment: You can just select the code type in the `raw` option to `JSON` you have it set to `text` in the image - That will set the header for you. Also, it’s returning a 400 request so I think the basics of a request is set up already.